# Pandas: Filter the the large dateframe and write to_csv in two different directories?

Tags: python, pandas

```
dir_1 = "C:\\Users\\kam\\"
dir_2 = "C:\\Users\\sam\\"

data = {'Name' : ['tom','bul','zack','doll','viru','sam','ram','zori'],'country':['CA','missing','NZ','IN','CA','missing', 'NZ', 'missing']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.to_string(index=False))

Name  country
tom       CA
bul  missing
zack       NZ
doll       IN
viru      CA
sam  missing
ram      NZ
zori  missing


[filename[1].to_csv(dir_1 + f'{filename[0]}.csv', index=False) for filename in df.groupby('country', axis='index')]
```

In the above code I am trying to save separate csv files in 'dir_1' based on 'country' and assigning the csv filename as country name (CA.csv, NZD.csv,IN.csv, missing.csv). But now i want to save 'missing' country in dir_2 as (missing.csv) and rest save in dir_1(CA.csv, NZD.csv,IN.csv). How can we extend the above code to solve the purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
missing_df = df[df['country'].eq('missing')]
missing_df.to_csv('/dir1/missing.csv')

country_df = df[~df['country'].eq('missing')] 
country_df.to_csv('/dir2/countries.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think you are creating single csv file in dir_2 and not separate csv files.

Comment: @mathew I am creating 2 csv's(`missing.csv` and `countries.csv`) in 2 different directories(`dir1` and `dir2`).

Answer (score 0):

```
[filename[1].to_csv(dir_1 + f'{filename[0]}.csv', index=False) if filename[0]!='' else filename[1].to_csv(dir_2 + 'missing.csv', index=False) for filename in df.groupby('country', axis='index')]
```

Comment: Thanks Billix. But there is the problem with code. Please check once. Its showing error.

Comment: @mathew oops, sorry about that. 
edit: changed ```!==``` to ```!=```